# Запятые (и точка)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

И третья мудрость: «Да проклянет Господь изменника!»(.)"Новое предложение".
Нужна ли тчк в скобках (зрительно хочется поставить)?

Затем(,) забрав сокровища, он направился к брату.
Нужна ли зпт в скобках?

Название сказки: «Если наестся(,) начнет бодаться».
Что лучше поставить в скобках: тире или зпт?

Он сказал: "Потому что(,) если наестся, начнет бодаться".
Нужна ли зпт в скобках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И третья мудрость: «Да проклянет Господь изменника!» Точка не ставится после прямой речи, если есть восклицательный знак.

Затем, забрав сокровища, он направился к брату. Наречие не входит в деепричастный оборот.

Название сказки: «Если наестся, начнет бодаться». В СПП основным знаком является запятая, увеличенной паузы нет.

Он сказал: "Потому что, если наестся, начнет бодаться".  Запятая ставится (не ставится только в случае двойного союза ЕСЛИ ...ТО). Здесь возможна перестановка: Потому что начнет бодаться, если наестся.

Пример:

Потому что, **если я этого не сделаю**, я посажу её в тюрьму. [Людмила Улицкая. Казус Кукоцкого [Путешествие в седьмую сторону света] // «Новый Мир», 2000]